# Pulling field names from SQL query

Tags: sql, database, dynamic, metadata

Is there a way to retrieve the field names from an actual query, similar to how you can retrieve field names from a table using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?  In essence, I'm wanting to accept an entire query as a parameter, and be able to build an empty table with the field names from said query.

Right now, I'm using a `STUFF()` function to replace the `SELECT` with `SELECT TOP 1` and replacing the `FROM` with a `INTO tablename FROM`, and then truncating tablename.  It works, but I need this to be able to handle complex queries where the first occurrence of FROM might not be the one I need (in case the user is using a subquery for a field, for example).

Comment: `CREATE TABLE xyz AS SELECT ...`

Comment: Indeed, plus `WHERE FALSE` if you need an empty table.

Comment: Perfect....just perfect.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it seems like the `CREATE TABLE xyz AS SELECT...` isn't supported by SSMS 2008 R2.  My bad for not including this.  It did give me the idea to change it to `SELECT x.* INTO tablename FROM (@sqlString) WHERE 1 = 0`, which I think will work for what I need.  Thanks again